# Excluding an ApplicationListener @Component in Spring Boot during tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to have my test unit up and running, and I have encountered a weird issue. My application uses an ApplicationListener class annotated as a @Component to perform an operation during startup.

During tests I have mocked the service that contains the logic, but I found that even though Mockito's when instructions work well in controller scope, the bean is not initialized for this ApplicationListener class: instead of returning what I define in the test unit, it returns either false or null - depending on the data type returned by each method in the service.

Since I have not found any way to initialize the mocked service from the test unit for the ApplicationListener class, I have decided to exclude it. To do so I have tried different approaches, being the one most often used that of creating a test application context and change its configuration. Unfortunately, nothing I have seen is working - so I am here asking for help. If possible, I would prefer not touching the ApplicationListener class and do all related coding in the test code.

I am interested in any of the two possible solutions, if they can be done:

1.- Get the mocked behaviour during the ApplicationListener execution, but I have read somewhere that this cannot be done

2.- Exclude the @Component from the test unit somehow.

**TestUnit.Java**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestConfigurationService { 
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private MockService mockService;

    private void initMockBean () throws Exception {
        when(mockService.isDoingSomething()).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        // Spring mock context application setup
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

        // Initialize ConsulService mock bean
        initMockBean ();
    }
}
```

**TestApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="my.base.package", excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = StartupConfiguration.class))
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Besides what is shown in the code, I have also tried this annotation in file TestApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={StartupConfiguration.class})
```

**StartupConfiguration.java**

```
@Component
public class StartupConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {   
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {     
        try {
            configurationService.updateConfiguration();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException ("Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**ConfigurationService.java**

```
public interface ConfigurationService {
    public void updateConfiguration () throws Exception;
}
```

**ConfigurationServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationService {     
    @Autowired
    private MService mockService;

    @Override
    public void updateConfiguration() throws Exception {    
        if (mockService.isDoingSomething()==false)
            throw new Exception ("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

**Versions**:

Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE,

Java 1.8

Comment: I'm a little confused about the issue you're having... Is the issue simply that you don't want Spring to initialize  `StartupConfiguration` during the test?

Comment: I need that either StartupConfiguration is not loaded for tests, so that the listener does not execute at all.

Comment: Another alternative could be mocking the application listener to return true, but if the inner mocked service did not initialize at that moment during startup, my guess is that mocking it is not possible either. But if it was possible, that would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, araxn1d. Your answer gave me the clue to solve this issue.

I mocked the StartupConfiguration class in TestUnit.java:

```
@MockBean
private StartupConfiguration startupConfiguration;
```

Though in this case I was lucky: application listeners don't have returning methods, so they don't need when test configuration. If I had required that some method there returned for example true or a value, this method would not apply.

But at least for application listeners, this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can create mock bean of the same type and mark it with `@Primary` annotation to replace real bean. You can achieve this by having test such configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(TestApplication.class)
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConfigurationService configurationService() {
        return Mockito.mock(ConfigurationService.class);
    }
}
```

then get this mock in test:

```
...
public class TestConfigurationService { 
    ...
    @Autowired
    ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(mockService.isDoingSomething()).thenReturn(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what `@MockBean` is already doing. Don[t confuse it with `@Mock` from Mockito.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yep, I missed it and my answer now has no value at all =(